# SSRS Only Showing 1 Instance of Report, Expecting Multiple

Tags: ssrs-2014

I'm new to SSRS so forgive me if this is an obvious answer. I'll try and simplify my problem as best I can:

I have a report that's based off of a query. On that report it has the fields Account ID and Mail Date from that query on the page. Not a tablix, just the fields.

When I run the query on the DB, it will return 100 records, so 100 distinct Account ID and Mail Date pairs.

When I run the report, I only get one instance of the report, the very first Account ID/Mail Date pair. I was expecting 100 instances of the report, one for each the Account ID/Mail Date pairs (that's how it worked in Oracle Forms, which I'm trying to convert).

Is there a configuration or setting I'm missing to get the expected behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few people have viewed this so here's the solution I used:

I created another report with my dataset, put a table on that report, set it break after each record, then put a subreport on the table that contained the original report and passed all the dataset values from the table to the subreport.

The subreport was then created with 1 record per page as I wanted.